# regex/preg_replace to replace subdomain

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i need to use preg_replace to replace two subdomain elements with a single element. my regex skills are virtually nonexistent. the urls are of the form:

```
user1.common.domain.org
user2.common.domain.org
something.common.domain.org
else.common.domain.org
```

and need to be replaced with:

```
newvalue.domain.org
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/164291

Comment: This is a poorly defined [mcve].  There are many ways to produce that kind of output, but there is a lack of specificity in the logical requirements.  Researchers should not need to read the accepted answer to understand the question.  We don't know if `'/[^.]+\.[^.]+/', $newvalue` will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace( '/[a-z0-9]+\.common/i' , 'newvalue' , $url );
```

Comment: This doesn't ensure that only domain.org values are replaced...it acts on anything with [a-z0-9]+\.common in the string

Comment: that is replacing "common.domain" with "newvalue". i.e. elements 2 and 3, instead of elements 1 and 2

Comment: @devy: provide an example because i don't get you. Codepad preferred

Comment: @Brian: no it replaces user1.common with newvalue

Comment: @yes123: I think devy means that if the string user1.common appeared somewhere else in the file, but it wasn't a domain (it wasn't followed by domain.org), your regex would still replace/match it. I think you would have to have positive look-ahead to ensure what follows it is a domain closing (like domain.org).

Comment: @yes123: [This](http://rubular.com/r/iUmU3FsUsd) should demonstrate my point.  As you see there, the regular expression matches things that don't fit his request (he requested to replace things with common.domain with domain, so the solution should ensure that it only applies to strings with domain in the proper order).

Comment: given the example provided that can't happen sorry. @devy: you aren't following the example provided :)

Comment: @yes123: You're right, your replace works correctly for this example.  I was merely pointing out that this may not work if there are other site names in the list that would get picked up by this regex as well (not a stretch of the imagination).

Comment: no problem but of course I would have changed accordingly my answer if his examples included this possibility :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_replace("/.+?(domain.+?)/", "newvalue.$1", "user1.common.domain.org");
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This problem might not be best-solved with a regular expression.  Try using `explode()`:

```
$exploded = explode('.', $hostname);
if( (count($exploded) == 4) and ($exploded[1] == 'common') )
{
    $exploded[0] = 'newvalue';
    unset($exploded[1]);
}

$hostname = implode('.', $exploded);
```

(where `$hostname` is the hostname you are checking [e.g., `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`)

The above code assumes that you are looking for hostnames that match the pattern `*.common.domain.org`, and that the hostname will always end with `domain.org`.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$sd = "user1.common.domain.org";

$sd = preg_replace('/.*?\.common\.(domain\.org)/i', 'newvalue.$1', $sd);

echo $sd ;
```

outputs  **newvalue.domain.org**

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```php
preg_replace('/\w+\.\w+(?=\.\w+\.\w+)/i', 'newvalue', 'user1.common.domain.org');
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This would be more concise:

For host:

```php
$newValue = 'newvalue';
$newHost = preg_replace("/^.+(?:\.common)(\.domain\.org)$/", "$newValue$1", $host);
```

*replaces string staring with any character one or more times + ".common" + ".domain" to "newvalue.domain.org"*

For url:

```php
$newValue = 'newvalue';
$newUrl = preg_replace("/^(https?:\/\/).+(?:\.common)(\.domain\.org)$/", "$1$newValue$2", $url);
```

*replaces string staring with "http://" or "https://" + any character one or more times + ".common" + ".domain" to "http://" or "https://" + "newvalue.domain.org"*

Answer (score -1):

This is only for if you can be sure it ends with domain.org:

```
preg_replace('/(?:.*?)\.(?:.*?)(\.domain\.org)/', $new_val."$1", $url);
```

Comment: Those `.*?` would be better as negated character classes.